# Azure WebJob - message processing is delayed

Tags: azure, azure-webjobs

I'm working on an Azure WebJob that is processing items from a Azure Storage Queue. There are cases the processing of a message is heavily delayed and I don't understand why.

```
JobHostConfiguration config = new JobHostConfiguration();
config.Queues.MaxPollingInterval = TimeSpan.FromSeconds(3);
```

I have seen that the Storage Explorer is showing this message in case of a delayed processing:

```
"Showing 0 of 1 messages in the queue"
```

My commandline-programm is showing in this situation the following message:

```
"Executing [...] - Reason: 'New queue message detected on 'synctasks'.'"
```

Typically the processing is going with by executing my method but in some cases it just stops here or is taking a long time.

Any ideas?